# Generate charts as image without UI rendering in .net/.net core

Tags: .net, pdf, charts, itext, .net-core

At my work place I am given the responisbiity to create charts/graphs in PDF format. We use iTextsharp for PDF creation. .NET Core/ASP.NET Core is used for Server Side processing.

I can definitely draw graphs using shapes and all, but that is humongous effort. And also, I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

I searched google to see if there are open soure libraries (.NET dlls) that can take data and render graphs in image format in process (meaning no need for an active UI). These images I can place in PDF using iTextsharp. I couldn't find any such match.

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting. is not available in .net core.

Comment: What were your search keywords? Did you take a look at static charts generator like https://www.image-charts.com ?

Comment: @FGRibreau , what i needed was .net dll